# How do i create Relational Model for Friends in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

So I have one model `User`, and `Friends`.

Problem is I want `user.friends` to show all friends regardless user A friended user B or user B friended A.

I thought i could create something like this

Friends
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :user

so it will be a simple join table between Users but i can see how this is not possible as easily.

Can i create table with 2 columns id_a, id_b and then in model do `has_many :friends, :through=> :id_a or :id_b`

Comment: What's the friend class? Aren't friends also users? In any case, self-referential tables are discussed in the Rails docs.

Comment: have a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association?view=asciicast

Comment: i've been watching it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to do this with a join table you could create `Friendships` with columns `friend_a_id` and `friend_b_id` and define the following relations:

On `User`:

```
has_many(
  :a_friendships, 
  class_name: "Friendship", 
  foreign_key: :friend_a_id, 
  primary_key: :id
)
has_many(
  :b_friendships, 
  class_name: "Friendship", 
  foreign_key: :friend_b_id, 
  primary_key: :id
)
has_many :friend_as, through: :b_friendships, source: :friend_a
has_many :friend_bs, through: :a_friendships, source: :friend_b
def friends
  friend_as + friend_bs
end
```

On `Friendship`:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to(
  :friend_a, 
  class_name: "User", 
  foreign_key: friend_a_id, 
  primary_key: :id
)
belongs_to(
  :friend_b, 
  class_name: "User", 
  foreign_key: friend_b_id, 
  primary_key: :id
)
```

`user.friends` will then return an active record containing all of the users who are in a friendship listing containing that user. This works by gathering all of the `friend_b`s in Friendships where the user is `friend_a` and vice versa.

This is assuming that you didn't mean that you have a `Friend` model, but rather that each `User` can be a friend to another `User`.